# Asking the legend option in high charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the legend bottom centre whenever I give the width: '100%' the legend is coming left side I want to keep in middle.

example code:

legend:{
backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255)',
Width : '100%',
},

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex or grid properties, it's make easier if you want the element to center.

`legend:{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255)',display: "grid", placeItems: "center"  }`

And place add some more info if you not want that answer. That help other to understand what problem really is